# I need help answering a few simple math problems related to permutations and probability

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Question 1: How many words can you make from the letters Texas if repeats are not allowed?

Question 2: How many words can you make from the letters Texas if repeats are allowed?

Question 3: What is the probability that you pick an Ace out of a standard deck of 52 cards?

Question 4: What is the probability you draw an ace, then a jack, and then another jack?

Question 5: True or False: Given infinite time, a monkey at a typewriter would type the words to King Lear infinitely many times.

The answers that I got are:

1. 5! = 120
2. 5^5 = 3,125
3. 4/52 = 1/13
4. without replacement: 8/16575 with replacement: 1/2197
5. True

I just wanted to be sure if the answers I got were correct, and I'd really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: For question 1, must you use *all* letters from `Texas`?  For example, is "sat" not an allowed word?  For question 2, must the word be of length five?  Assuming the answer to each of my questions for clarification are yes, then your answers are almost all correct.  Check again your calculation for question 4 when it is without replacement.  What is the chance of drawing an ace out of 52 cards?  Drawing a jack out of 51 cards which is missing an ace?  Drawing a jack out of 50 cards which is missing an ace **and a jack**?

Comment: As for the infinite monkey theorem... that is a gross simplification to the result and it is missing several key assumptions.  Namely, each time the monkey presses a button on the typewriter, he chooses a button independently at random with positive probability for each button to be pressed.  Also that the monkey presses buttons infinitely many times.  If the monkey has a strange obsession with the spacebar and carriage return and *only* hits those buttons (and never hits any letters), even with infinite time, no words will have been typed, much less any famous works like King Lear.

Comment: This is one of the times when I suppose people will not be very upset that one posted "question" actually contains multiple independent questions, since you did the work for all the questions and (mostly) did it well enough that we can just say those parts are fine.

Comment: Yes for question 1 you must use all letters from Texas, and for question 2 the word must be five letters in length. Without replacement, the chance of drawing an ace out of 52 cards is 4/52. The chance of drawing a jack out of 51 cards that is missing an ace is 4/51. The chance of drawing a jack out of 50 cards that is missing an ace and a jack is 3/50. So would the answer be 4 x 4 x 3 / 52 x 51 x 50 = 2/5525? Is the answer I got with replacement correct? Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Given an infinite amount of time that typewriter will almost surely be covered in an infinite amount of monkey poop.

Comment: Your answer $$\frac{4 \cdot 4 \cdot 3}{52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50} = \frac{2}{5525}$$ for drawing an ace, then a jack, then another jack without replacement is correct.  For future reference, here is a [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Welcome to MathSE.

Answer (score 1):

$1, 2$ and $3$ seems correct but not $4$.

For question $4$ without replacement

$(4/52) \cdot (4/51) \cdot (3/50)$

with replacement your calculation is correct.